# How to save faces from an image into a collection on AWS Rekognition using python

Tags: python, collections, amazon-rekognition

I have created a collection name and now I want to add images to the collection so I can run function on them like compare_faces.  The problem is that I do not how to save to a specific collection that I have created when I run functions like detect_faces.  AWS documentation doesn't show the syntax for adding a CollectionId to any of these functions to save faces that I have detected to a collection so I can use them for comparison purposes later.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you will upload images with metadata to s3, each image should contain only one face with one name provided as metadata

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

# Get list of objects for indexing
images=[('image01.jpeg','Albert Einstein'),
      ('image02.jpeg','Candy'),
      ('image03.jpeg','Armstrong'),
      ('image04.jpeg','Ram'),
      ('image05.jpeg','Peter'),
      ('image06.jpeg','Shashank')
      ]

# Iterate through list to upload objects to S3   
    for image in images:
    file = open(image[0],'rb')
    object = s3.Object('rekognition-pictures','index/'+ image[0])
    ret = object.put(Body=file,
                    Metadata={'FullName':image[1]}
                    )
```

Now you have to do indexing with lambda function that will do your work and store faces to your rekognition collection as well as store a name to each face in a dynamodb table , both of which you can reference later while using other api's such as compare faces

```
from __future__ import print_function

import boto3
from decimal import Decimal
import json
import urllib

print('Loading function')

dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition')


# --------------- Helper Functions ------------------

def index_faces(bucket, key):

    response = rekognition.index_faces(
        Image={"S3Object":
            {"Bucket": bucket,
            "Name": key}},
            CollectionId="family_collection")
    return response

def update_index(tableName,faceId, fullName):
    response = dynamodb.put_item(
        TableName=tableName,
        Item={
            'RekognitionId': {'S': faceId},
            'FullName': {'S': fullName}
            }
        ) 

# --------------- Main handler ------------------

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get the object from the event
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.unquote_plus(
        event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))

    try:

        # Calls Amazon Rekognition IndexFaces API to detect faces in S3 object 
        # to index faces into specified collection

        response = index_faces(bucket, key)

        # Commit faceId and full name object metadata to DynamoDB

        if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
            faceId = response['FaceRecords'][0]['Face']['FaceId']

            ret = s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=key)
            personFullName = ret['Metadata']['fullname']

            update_index('family_collection',faceId,personFullName)

        # Print response to console
        print(response)

        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Error processing object {} from bucket {}. ".format(key, bucket))
       raise e
```